# Scaling content in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am displaying some content in a UIWebView on both an iPhone and an iPad (same content, two different apps). On the iPhone, the content fills the entire 320px in width, but on the iPad, it does not - it seems to only be about 240px across.

I don't have control of the content, but I did find this in the source:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width = 320" /><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" /></head>
```

Can anyone suggest why this wouldn't be working on an iPad app, and if there's anything I can do about it without being able to change the HTML? I'd rather not manipulate it through javascript either, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what is going wrong, or what effect you are trying to achieve, but I usually use a tag like this in my UIWebView-based views:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Agreed, but in this case I don't have access to the HTML.